# Генерация проекта

Tags: android-studio

При создании Bundle проекта выдаётся ошибка. Причем создаю уже второй проект, но ошибка вылезает первый раз, что делать не знаю.

> Key was created with errors:
>
> Warning:
> The JKS keystore uses a proprietary forms. It is recommended it to migrate to PKCS12

Comment: не уверен, что ошибка в этом месте, здесь вас просто предупреждают, что лучше бы поменять на PKCS12

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: да это вам не поможет собрать проект, но если хотите загуглите эту строку, есть куча туторалов

Comment: Лучше ошибку целиком скиньте